# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 - Root category must be an integer value

Tags: sql, installation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying a fresh installation of prestashop 1.6.1.4, first I got `SQL error on query All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead​` and used the following solution https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/480947-error-presta-on-server-2012-r2-sql-error-on-query-all-parts-of-a-primary-key-must-be-not-null/

But now, after install, when I go to admin > catalog I get:

```
[PrestaShopException]

Root category must be an integer value
at line 212 in file classes/helper/HelperTreeCategories.php

207.     }
208. 
209.     public function setRootCategory($value)
210.     {
211.         if (!Validate::isInt($value)) {
212.             throw new PrestaShopException('Root category must be an integer value');
213.         }
214. 
215.         $this->_root_category = $value;
216.         return $this;
217.     }
HelperTreeCategoriesCore->setRootCategory - [line 2504 - controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php] - [1 Arguments]
AdminProductsControllerCore->initContent - [line 189 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 58 - admin1/index.php]
```

$value is empty

**Note:** I'm trying to install this specific version because I'm debugging:

[Cannot save or edit product data in Prestashop 1.6.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847143/cannot-save-or-edit-product-data-in-prestashop-1-6-1-4?noredirect=1#comment68911531_40847143)

Comment: How do you install this fresh shop?? Using standard Prestashop install method?? Because this version has no installation problem as far as I know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have mentioned appears if the home category is deleted anyhow. Try adding a home category, make it the root category.

For more details you can visit:

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/NM-606